# angular/cli give me error when install it

Tags: angular, angular-cli

when i install angular in a terminal after setup give me this error 
I have installed:
node v6.10.3

```
npm ERR! Darwin 17.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/macmini/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried running it as root?

Comment: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

please try in administrative mode in your system

```
npm install -g @angular/cl
```